# How can an attacker hijack js/css content?

Tags: dns, cdn

I just encounter an issue, the cached js files showed porn site

[image: Network diagram]

Here's the simple network diagram.

https://cdn.mysite.com/js/app.js shows a porn site, but if I add in query string

https://cdn.mysite.com/js/app.js?t=20180928130702, then it displays the correct content

[image: AWS S3 show correct file]

The content in AWS S3 is correct.

How does the attacker alter the content in the middle? How to prevent this?

*P/S: a temporary solution is disable the CDN for now*